# Record-level Security in LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I'm working on a record-level security system for a LINQ-to-SQL app.  I currently have a wrapper around the DataContext's GetTable method that joins T to a user cross-reference table.  T is any class that implements my ISecurable interface:

```
public interface ISecurable
{
    bool CanRead { get; set; }
    bool CanUpdate { get; set; }
    bool CanDelete { get; set; }
}
```

My base repository class performs the join and updates each story's CanRead, CanUpdate, and CanDelete properties for the specified user:

```
var storiesVisibleToUser = repository.Get<Story>( user );
```

I'd like to replace the wrapper with an extension method, so I can do something like this:

```
var storiesVisibleToUser = repository.Get<Story>().ApplySecurity( user );
```

It's a subtle change, but will greatly decrease the coupling between the security code and the general data access code, so it will give me more flexibility for adding stuff like group-level security.

The problem is that the ApplySecurity extension method doesn't have access to the original DataContext, so it can't use GetTable<> to retrieve the cross-reference records.

#### Two questions:

1. Is there any way to get an IQueryable's DataContext, short of [subclassing/wrapping it and passing the context in to the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486947/customizing-iqueryablet)?
2. Is an extension method the "proper" way to do this, or should I stick with a method in my repository that would have access to the original context?

Comment: I wouldn't use an extension method here.  Breaking the step that applies security to your data leaves your code open to retrieve the data WITHOUT security applied which kind of defeats the purpose.  I would leave the security encapsulated in your repository methods as you have it.  If you go this route you don't have to be concerned with your question #1.

Comment: There will be places in the code where records will need to be retrieved even if the current user doesn't have access.  For example, we may want to show the user a list of story names, including those he doesn't otherwise have read access to.  In the existing code, the Get<T> method has an overload with a boolean argument that is used to optionally include such records.  There are other places where an admin user needs to know which users have access to certain records, so calling the extension method multiple times for different users could be beneficial.

Comment: If the user can "see" the data, then by definition, they have access to it.... am I missing something?

Comment: @Nate: The user is not the code.  The code can perform various transformations on the data before sending it to the user in the form of JSON, HTML, etc.  I'll admit the boundary is a little fuzzy.  The security settings are ultimately more of a guideline that the code should follow, not a hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: To qualify my last comment: An ideal setup would probably have custom  "roles", instead of just "CanRead", "CanUpdate", and "CanDelete".  That would eliminate the fuzziness where users can see data in certain views that they don't otherwise have CanRead privs to.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create an association between the Story and the cross-reference table.  That then makes the other table available to Story queries without needing a reference to the original context.